# Why are these two Python unicode strings different?

Tags: python, string, unit-testing, unicode

I'm writing some unit tests in Python, and I now have a rather strange error. I compare two strings, which seem completely the same, yet I get an assertion error. The code below prints out what I commented behind:

```
print type(a), len(a), a  # <type 'unicode'> 12 € 290.000,00
print type(b), len(b), b  # <type 'unicode'> 12 € 290.000,00
print a == b  # False
```

So to find out which of the characters are different, I print them out and compare the string character by character:

```
for enum, i in enumerate(a):
    print a[enum], b[enum], a[enum] == b[enum]
```

this prints out:

```
€ € True
   False  # <== THE SPACE IS NOT EQUAL?!!?
2 2 True
9 9 True
0 0 True
. . True
0 0 True
0 0 True
0 0 True
, , True
0 0 True
0 0 True
```

So to my surprise, the space is the character which makes these two strings not equal. I really don't get this though. Why would a space in two unicode strings be different?

Does anybody know whats wrong here? All tips are welcome!

Comment: My psychic powers tell me one of these spaces is a non-breaking space (`U+00A0`), not a "normal" space (`U+0020`).

Comment: Check out the actual code of different character. There's plenty of characters that looks same (as whitespace)

Comment: for enum, i in enumerate(a): print ord(a[enum]), ord(b[enum]), a[enum] == b[enum]  # see what the codepoint is

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unicode defines a bunch of different space characters:

[image: table of Unicode space characters]

*(table via https://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/chars/spaces.html).*

To see exactly what's going on, mod your code like:

```
from unicodedata import name

for enum, i in enumerate(a):
    print name(a[enum]), name(b[enum]), a[enum] == b[enum]
```

...and the exact characters in use will be made explicit.

Comment: That sucks. So would you know how I could convert all spaces in a unicode string to one specific (most common) type of space?

Comment: It doesn't suck at all.

Comment: Alright, I just read about no-break spaces and why they are useful. Christian was right; it doesn't suck at all :). So I fixed it by replacing the no-break spaces for normal spaces by doing this: `b.replace(u"\u00A0", " ")`. Thanks for enlightening me!

Comment: @kramer65: Unicode provides a rich assortment of spaces. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character#Unicode

Comment: I'am not familiar with unicode normalizations, but may be this helps:  unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', u"_\U00000020_\U000000A0_\U00002000_")