# Indent pretty JSON in Google Sheet Apps Script

Tags: javascript, json, google-apps-script

I would like to show an alert with a pretty JSON, but it doesn't get indented well.

Here's the JS code I'm using :

```
var jsonText = JSON.stringify(jsonObject, null, 2)
SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(jsonText);
```

And here is the indentation I get as a result :

```
...
"xxx": "",
"xxx": ""
},
{
"xxx": "yyy",
"xxx": "yyy",
"xxx": "",
"xxx": ""
}
]
```

It's missing the tab indentation, any idea how I could fix this?

Comment: Using, `alert(JSON.stringify([{"x":1,"y":2},{"x":1,"y":2}], null, 2))` I can see the indentation with a native Chrome browser alert dialog. Google's app-scripts [dialog](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs) seems to render the text in HTML. So it will honor the new-lines in your formatted JSON, but it will trim the leading white-space on each line. This is normal when setting HTML text for an element. You would have to specify white-space as `pre` somehow, or add literal space escape characters to your JSON text. Something along the lines of `str.replace(/ /g, '&nbsp;')`.

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl Tyour comment can be a good legitimate answer for this question. You may want to post this an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems normal space `\u{0020}` characters are removed from SpreadsheetApp `Ui.alert()` function. You may use any of the other space characters mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28434169) as a space character. `\u{2000}` works:

```
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(
    JSON.stringify(
      { x: 1, y: 2, z: [1, 2, { a: { b: 1 } }] },
      null,
      '\u{2000}'.repeat(2)
    )
  );
```

Comment: That is much nicer.

Comment: Thanks ! That works perfectly and indeed it's quite clean

Answer (score 3):

You can see the indentations in a text area:

```
function onMyEdit(e) {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(`<textarea cols="30" rows="12">${JSON.stringify(e,['range','columnStart','rowStart','value','source','rowEnd','rowStart','oldValue'],10)}</textarea>`),'Simple Dialog');
}
```

[image]

Comment: Great answer, thanks. The issue with all the ones involving using non-breaking unicode characters is that they don't parse as valid JSON if you then copy-paste the output somewhere else. This answer creates both valid JSON and well formatted JSON.

Answer (score 2):

The only way I know to pretty-print JSON in your alert window is to force `JSON.stringify()` to use hard-coded non-breaking space characters for the `space` parameter.

Example:

```js
function popup() {
  var jsonObject = [{"x":1,"y":2},{"x":1,"y":2}];
  // warning - the two spaces used below need to be non-breaking spaces:
  var jsonText = JSON.stringify(jsonObject, null, "  ");
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(jsonText);
}
```

This generates the following result in the alert window:

[image]

**Note** - You probably cannot copy/paste those non-breaking spaces from my answer - I think you will only end up copying regular spaces, which will not give you the required indentation (they will be collapsed as per standard HTML rules regarding consecutive whitespace).

So, instead, you can manually enter the NBSP characters using your keyboard.

For me on Windows this was by me holding down the `ALT` key and typing the number sequence `0160`.

On a Mac it is `opt` + `space`.

For more systems, see [nbsp keyboard entry methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space#Keyboard_entry_methods).

---

Personally, I find this a bit unpleasant - you cannot easily tell that these are hard-coded NBSPs - they look like regular whitespaces in your source code. That is why I added a comment in the code. If there is a cleaner solution, that would get my vote.

(And using the `&nbsp;` sequence did not work for me - it was treated as a literal string).